# Palindrome of a number - No console log

Tags: variables, numbers, palindrome

So I tried to write a code that finds the largest palindromic number from two (3 spaces long) multiplied numbers. Does my code work fine or are there no palindromes for this?

```js
function checkPalindrom(str) {
    return str === str.split('').reverse().join('');
}; //Declares the funciton to check if a string is a palindrome

var x = 999;
var y = 999;
var z = 0;
var n = z.toString(); //Declares that n is the string of z

for (i=0; i<899; i++) { //For loop: counts from 0 to 899
    x*y===z; //Is this correct? z is set equal to x*y
        if(checkPalindrom(n) === true) { //If n is a palindrome,
            console.log(n); //Write out the palindrome
        } else {
            x-=1; //subtract 1 from x and run again
        }
};
```

Also, what is the best way to check for all combinations of 3 digit numbers? Because right now I am just checking for any number from 100 to 999, but I actually need to check for all combinations...

Comment: x*y===z; //Is this correct? z is set equal to x*y ---- No, write it as z = x*y;

Comment: it still only runs through once. How do i iterate through all combinations of x and y between 100 and 999?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post has a few problems, as well as multiple questions in it.  I'll try to hone in on the major stuff but, as this is a fairly standard type of Programming 101 homework question, I'm not going to give you an exact answer right out.

First off, there are three different 'equals' in javascript, =, ==, and ===.  A single = is an assignment operator and it always works from right to left.  Thus,

```
    var x = 2;
```

assigns the value of 2 to the variable x.  In your code,

```
    x*y === z;
```

has a couple of problems.  First off, it is backwards.  Secondly, it uses === but should be using =.

```
    z = x*y;
```

That is what you were trying to put here.

In javascript, == and === are both comparitives.   The triple === adds type comparison and is stronger but generally unnecessary.  In almost all cases, == is sufficient.  But, what it does is compare the values like inside an if statement:

```
    if(x == 2)
```

This just checks if the value of x is equal to the value of 2, but the values themselves do not change.

Ok, for your other question: "number from 100 to 999, but I actually need to check for all combinations..."

The best way to handle this is a double loop:

```
    var z;
    for(var x = 100; x < 1000; x++)
        for(var y = x; y < 1000; y++)
           z = x*y;
```

This will first let x = 100, then check 100 * every number from 100 to 999.  Then you let x = 101 and check 101* every number from 101 to 999.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkPalindrom(str) {
    return str === str.split('').reverse().join('');
}; //Declares the funciton to check if a string is a palindrome

var x;
var y;
var z;
var n;
var max = 0;

for (x=999; x >= 100; x--) {
   for (y=999; y >= 100; y--) {
      z = x*y;
      n = z.toString();
      if(checkPalindrom(n) === true && max < z) {
         console.log(n);
         max = z;
      }
   }
}
```